# LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, header, компоновщик

Уважаемые коллеги, есть у меня основной файл - "test.cpp":

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <common.h>
#include "String.h" // Здесь определяется мой класс строки
int main()
{
   double d = 12.536;
   double r = common::round(d);
   return 0x0000;
}
```

Файл "common.h" - это мой собственный заголовочный файл:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef COMMON_h
#define COMMON_h
namespace common
{
   double round(double val, unsigned precision = 0);
}
#endif
```

Этот файл лежит где-то на диске D:\, и в компиляторе я в свойствах проектах добавил директорию поиска включаемых файлов. Он его прекрасно находит, но при сборке приложения выдаёт ошибку LNK2019.
Рядом с этим файлом в той же директории лежит "common.cpp":

```
#pragma once
#include <common.h>

double common::round(double val, int precision)
{
   /// Тут какой-то код
   return 0.0;
}
```

Если я помещаю реализацию метода round() внутрь файла "common.h", то всё работает нормально, но только если я единожды подключаю этот файл. А вот если я его включу и в основной "test.cpp" и в "String.h", то уже выкидывает ошибку LNK2005. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне решить эту проблему. Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

**Теоретическая часть.**

Когда компилятор находит определение функции, то он добавляет код функции в объектный файл и экспортирует её имя. Если определить функцию в заголовочном файле, то этот заголовочный файл включается в текст *.cpp файла и будет создан объектный файл с экспортируемой функцией. Если несколько файлов включат этот заголовочный файл себе, то получится, что в нескольких объектных файлах окажутся функции с одинаковыми именами. При линковке объектных файлов линковщик не сможет выбрать нужную функцию, т.к. их будет несколько с одинаковыми именами.

**Практическая часть**: есть файлы main.cpp, common.h и common.cpp.

**Пример 1:** функция `round()` в объявлена в common.h и определена в common.cpp

Лучший вариант. Функция будет создана только в объектном файле common.obj. При линковке вместе main.obj и common.obj будет только одна функция. Всё ОК!

**Пример 2:** функция `round()` определена в common.h.

Плохой вариант. Этот заголовочный файл включат main.cpp и common.cpp. Получатся два объектных файла main.obj и common.obj, которые будут иметь в себе определение функции `round()`. При линковке вместе этих объектных файлов будет ошибка линковки, т.к. линковщик увидит две функции с одинаковыми именами.

**Решения:**

- Не определять функции в заголовке, только объявлять их сигнатуры;
- Определять функции в заголовке, но включать этот заголовок только в один файл с кодом. Данное решение сильно ограничивает в архитектурных решениях;
- Определять функции в заголовке с модификатором `inline`. Inline функции не являются так таковыми функциями. Компилятор на месте их вызова вставляет тело функции.

Comment: У вас что теоретическая, что практическая, части хромают. Если компилятор находит определение функции, то экспортирует ее только если у нее `extern` линковка. А `inline` функции являются вполне себе обычными функциями и наличие этого спецификатора ничего не говорит о том, будет ли эта функция реально встраиваться в место вызова или нет.

Comment: @VTT Отличное замечание о `inline` функциях. Указание `inline` является лишь рекомендацией для компилятора. Если функция не встроилась в код, а создалась функция, то она помечается weak символом в объектном файле. Как только компоновщик найдет один из weak символов, остальные будут проигнорированы. Даже если компилятор проигнорирует модификатор, компоновка пройдет успешно.
Смело можно ставить встраиваемую функцию в один *.h-файл и использовать его в различных единицах трансляции. Нужно обновить ответ. Спасибо! :)

Answer (score 0):

Если пишите реализацию в заголовочном файле, то объявляйте функцию как `inline`. Тогда наличие реализации этой функции в каждой единице трансляции не будет ошибкой, линкер возьмет любую из реализаций (которые должны быть одинаковы):

```
namespace common
{
    inline double round(double val, unsigned precision = 0)
    {
       … 
    }
}
```

Comment: Но у меня не все функции такие маленькие, как double round(), и на них inline попросту бесполезно

Comment: @YashiroShow `inline` и размер функции никак не связаны. Возможно вас вводит в заблуждение сам термин `inline`, однако он в общем случае ничего не говорит о том, встраивается функция или нет.

Comment: Ну нам просто в университете вот только недавно объясняли, что если реализация inline функции достаточно длинная компилятор её оставит в виде функции и не будет подставлять

Comment: @YashiroShow Вполне может быть. Собственно то, что она остается в виде функции не проблема.

Comment: @YashiroShow: Это совершенно не важно, подставит компилятор вашу функцию или нет. Назначение `inline` - это подавлять ошибку LNK2005 для функций, реализованных в заголовочных файлах.

Comment: @YashiroShow Встраивается ли тело этой функции в другую или нет - в данном контексте совершенно не важно. Важно то, что линкер не будет против наличия реализации этой функции в нескольких единицах трансляции.

Comment: VTT и AnT, Спасибо Вам, inline действительно помог :)

Answer (score 0):

Где лежит ваш `common.cpp` - "рядом" или "не рядом" - не имеет никакого значения. Вы должны сами явно добавить ваш `common.cpp` файл в ваш проект, чтобы он компилировался и линковался вместе со всеми остальными файлами программы, т.е. вместе с `test.cpp`.

Вы этого, очевидно, не сделали. Пока вы этого не сделаете - будет ошибка линковки LNK2019.

---

Либо так, либо избавляйтесь от `common.cpp` вообще и реализуйте вашу функцию в `common.h` как `inline`.